# How to answer this kind of diode problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

I have this problem here where I need to find V2 in 3 different cases and I have trouble of knowing how to take on the problem. Could someone please lead me into the right direction. I can't really find anything on how to go on this kind of problems.

[image]

Comment: How would you find V2 if the diode was not there? What is your general approach to solving circuits with diodes? We don't hand out homework solutions here, you need to show a significant amount of work and ask a specific question.

Comment: I have a hint question. Is the diode forward biased in any (or more) of the scenarios? What is the relative voltage across 2 parallel components?

Comment: What makes you think that there's be any resonance in this circuit?

Comment: Remove the diode and work out the Thevenin equivalent circuit.  For each voltage would the diode conduct if not you have your answer.  If it would conduct you know \$ V_T \$ so the diode sets \$ V_2 \$ and if you want you can work out the current in the diode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [@Hilmar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/65423/hilmar) gave a very good answer, I will present a more mathematical approach using the [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation)

---

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpgAL0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_\text{D}+\text{I}_2\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) and the Shockley diode equation, we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{D}=\text{I}_\text{s}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_1}{\eta\text{kT}}\right)-1\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Assuming room-temperature, \$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=10\space\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$\eta=\frac{3}{2}\$, I used Mathematica to find:

```
In[1]:=Is = 10^(-12);
\[Eta] = 3/2;
T = 20 + (5463/20);
q = (1602176620898/1000000000000)*10^(-19);
k = (1380649/1000000)*10^(-23);
Vin = 1;
R1 = x;
R2 = x;
x = 10000;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == ID + I2, I1 == (Vin - V1)/R1, 
   ID == Is*(Exp[(q*V1)/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1), I2 == V1/R2, 
   ID \[Element] Reals && I1 \[Element] Reals && I2 \[Element] Reals &&
     V1 \[Element] Reals}, {ID, I1, I2, V1}]]

Out[1]={{ID -> -(1/1000000000000) + (
    24284235261 ProductLog[(
      801088310449 E^(80108831845988310449/6071058815250000000))/
      6071058815250000000])/3204353241796000, 
  I1 -> 99999999/2000000000000 + (
    24284235261 ProductLog[(
      801088310449 E^(80108831845988310449/6071058815250000000))/
      6071058815250000000])/6408706483592000, 
  I2 -> 100000001/2000000000000 - (
    24284235261 ProductLog[(
      801088310449 E^(80108831845988310449/6071058815250000000))/
      6071058815250000000])/6408706483592000, 
  V1 -> 100000001/200000000 - (
    121421176305 ProductLog[(
      801088310449 E^(80108831845988310449/6071058815250000000))/
      6071058815250000000])/3204353241796}}

In[2]:=N[%1]

Out[2]={{ID -> 5.03226*10^-7, I1 -> 0.0000502516, I2 -> 0.0000497484, 
  V1 -> 0.497484}}
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. I assume that you used Vin = 1 V am I correct?

Comment: @Vetenskap yes, that is true.

Comment: I just have to ask, I havn't been using Matematica in a very long time and when I try to put the code and evaluate it, it says "SetDelayed: Tag In in In[1] is Protected." Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Vetenskap Yes, run the code without In[1]:=, that is to indicate the input number.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see. After the first output you type in N[%1] am I correct?

Comment: @Vetenskap Yes but is also possible to write NSolve instead of Solve in the first code, it will give you the approximate solutions.

Comment: Oh I see, now it turned out. :)

Comment: @Vetenskap You're welcome, and in my code, you can change all the parameters. For example, you can change the temperature.

Comment: @Vetenskap While this answer may be interesting, I don't think it is what your instructor is looking for. The question stipulates that the forward voltage of the diode **is** 0.7V, and this answer has ignored that qualification. I think your instructor is looking for a different approach entirely.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson if it is interesting why the -1? As I mention in my answer, the different answer to this question gives the desired result.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @ElliotAlderson. I think he wants me to use the forward voltage of the diode. The thing is, I have not been able to understand how to approach the problem because our professor only stated on a clip (due to corona all the universities all closed -> harder to ask professor questions and get answer fast) that you can solve the problem with thevenin equivalent and if Vth is greater that 0.7 V then the diode is 0.7 V. The explanation was not great, and I've been trying to see if anything is writen in my book or find anything on the internet, but I haven't been lucky.

Comment: @Jan The +1 or -1 is given if the answer is **useful** or **not useful**, not because it was interesting or clever or had lots of good equations. Your answer was not really an answer at all, because you assumed a different question than the one that was asked. Mathematica is not needed for most of the questions on this site, including this one.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

1. Calculate V2 for all cases without the Diode present
2. Calculate V2 for all cases with R2 being "open"
3. Combine steps 1 and 2